# How to access only one certain page typing any url

Tags: .htaccess

I mean I have one page, for example `show_content.php`. That page fetches mysql data, based on `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

If user types for example, `www.domain/any-page` I want to show (access) only `show_content.php`.

How to do that?

In .htaccess or httpd.conf must write `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_content.php?$1`

Is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in your `HTACCESS` in order to be sure nobody can access at all:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "show_content.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

And after your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_content.php?$1
```